# supertest and checking DynamoDB before and after using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, amazon-dynamodb, supertest

I'd like to test my `koa` API routes using `supertest` and check what's in DynamoDB before and after to make sure that the end point did what was intended.

```
// app related
const pool = require('../../src/common/pool');
const app = require('../../server');
// for testing
const uuid = require('uuid');
const supertest = require('supertest');
// listen on port 40002
const request = supertest.agent(app.listen(4002));
describe('test', () => {
  it.only('should', async (done) => {
    debugger;
    const id = uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, '');
    await pool.add(id, 'data', 30);
    return request
      .get('/api/1')
      .expect(204)
      // .then(async (res) => {
      // .then((res) => {
      .end((res) => {
        // still returns 'data' instead of 'dataNew' after the route is hit
        const record = await pool.get(id);
        debugger;
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

In the code above, I'm creating a record in the db, then I hit the end point, and I tried a `then()` and an `end()` chained function to check the db once again. The end point will just `data` to `dataNew` and in the `then()` function, it still returns the original `data`.

Any ideas on how I can verify the new record in the db ?

References:

- [Supertest: Verify database after request](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/05/supertest-verify-in-database-after-ended-request.html) - In TLDR at the bottom, the solution was to use `co`. I tried this and had issues probably cause I'm using `await` instead of generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above was fixed by chaining the `pool.add()` which returns a promise, to the supertest `request` and then `await`ing the record to verify it. Sometimes it still gets the record too quickly because the `pool.update()` method is not `await`ed within the end point that `request` is hitting.

```
describe('test', () => {
  it.only('should', async () => {
    const id = uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, '');
    await pool.add(id, 'data', 30).then(() => {
      return request
        .get('/api/1')
        .expect(204)
        // check custom headers
        //.expect('pool-before', 'data')
        //.expect('pool-after', 'dataModified')
        .then(async (res) => {
          const record = await pool.get(id);
          debugger;
          expect('dataModified').to.equal(record.fields.S);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

The only other way I can think of is to check the value via a custom header, a delay, or use a mock.

Let me know if anyone has a better solution.